# display sub categories assoccited with each post in a category archive page

Tags: posts, categories

i have wordpress blog with many posts. each posts associated with many categories and sub categories. i want to display sub categories assoccited with each post in a category archive page.

for example, if user clicks on MBA category all posts with category MBA will display. in which, i want to display all sub categories of MBA associted with each post. ie, some post contain mba in london, mba in US as child categories of MBA. or other post may contain MBA in UAE as child category of MBA. all child categories associated with each post should display with posts. please help.

Thankz very much...

Comment: I asked this again since this post was unanswered, you can find the answer here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/205647/category-archive-list-subcategories-of-each-post

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Category Archive, list subcategories of each post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/205647/category-archive-list-subcategories-of-each-post)

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/158156/custom-post-type-archive-organized-by-category