# Custom post type archive organized by category

Tags: wp-query, loop, custom-post-type-archives, php

I'm trying to display a custom post type archive page which displays all the articles of a a custom post type in columns.  The columns organize them in their assigned category.

On the main page, I do this successfully with regular posts.  I loop thru each category, generate a column, and then loop thru each post within than category to populate the column:

```
get_header(); ?>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="categories">
            <?php
            $cats = get_categories();

            foreach ( $cats as $cat ) {
                $cat_id = $cat->term_id; ?>
                <div class="column" id="c0">
                    <h2><?php echo $cat->name; ?></h2>

                <?php query_posts( "cat=$cat_id&posts_per_page=100" );

                if ( have_posts() ) {
                    while ( have_posts() ) {
                        the_post();
                        the_title();
                    }

                    wp_reset_postdata();
                ?>

                </div> <!-- /column -->

                <?php } //post
            } ?> <!-- /foreach -->
        </div> <!-- /categories -->
    </div> <!-- /content -->
```

---

But within the custom post type I use this code and it generates and displays all the categories, but only displays 1 post per category.

```
get_header();

if(have_posts()) { ?>

    <div id="content">
        <div class="categories">
            <?php
            $args = array (
                'orderby'    => 'name',
                'order'      => 'ASC',
                'hide_empty' => true,
                //'number'    => '4'
            );

            $terms = get_terms( 'bookmark_categories', $args );
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>

            <div class="column" id="c0">
                <div class="category">
                    <h2><?php echo $term->slug ?></h2>
                    <p class="count">
                        <?php
                        $items = get_posts( array (
                            'post_type'   => 'bookmarks',
                            'numberposts' => - 1,
                            'taxonomy'    => 'bookmark_categories',
                            'term'        => $term->name
                        ) );

                        $count = count( $items );
                        echo $count;
                        ?>

                    </p>
                </div>

                <?php
                $post_args = array (
                    'post_type'           => 'bookmarks',
                    'bookmark_categories' => $term->name
                );
                $query     = new WP_Query( $post_args );

                while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                    $query->the_post();
                    $url = get_post_meta($post->ID,'link_url',true); ?>

                <div class="link">
                    <center>

                        <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" target="_blank" title="">
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
                        </a>

                    </center>
                </div>

                <?php } // while

                wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            </div> <!-- /column -->
            <?php } ?> <!-- /foreach -->
        </div> <!-- /categories -->
    </div> <!-- /content -->

<?php } else { // if posts
    get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );
}

get_footer();
```

Comment: Why are you using `offset => 1`?

Comment: Ah, that was redundant code from something else.  I should have removed that line.  I did now, but it has no effect on my current issue.

Comment: I think you should be using `$term->slug` in the args rather than `$term->name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use [`query posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) ever, my emphasis. It is just a bad function to use

> **Note:** This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes. As explained later, there are better, more performant options to alter the main query. query_posts() is overly simplistic and problematic way to modify main query of a page by replacing it with new instance of the query. It is inefficient (re-runs SQL queries) and will outright fail in some circumstances (especially often when dealing with posts pagination).

Also, `wp_reset_query` should be used for `query_posts`. `wp_reset_postdata` is meant to be used for [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts), which is the correct functions to use to create custom queries.

For additional info, check out [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155976/31545) I recently done.

`get_posts` uses the same parameters as `WP_Query`. Whenever you work with taxonomies and terms and in general with a `tax_query`, the default field that is used to retrieve the relevant info is `term_id`. `slug` is also valid and can also be used.

> **field (string)** - Select taxonomy term by ('term_id'(default) or 'slug')

So change `$term->name` to either `$term->term_id` or `$term->slug`

Comment: Hope you got a notification to this answer. The notification system is a big stuff up this weekend.

Comment: The whitespace can't be the problem, it's just ignored by php.