# Display posts on category archive organized into subcategories?

Tags: categories, theme-development, archives

I have been trying to achieve this as part of a WordPress theme, where users can assign a FAQ style template to a Post category of their choice, which is then organized into subcategories for easy browsing.

There is an interesting [blog post](https://wpshout.com/how-to-display-posts-on-a-category-page-divided-into-their-respective-subcategories/) about this, but it's rather difficult to understand, and I suspect overly complicated.

For example, something like this:

> **Billing Questions**
>
> - Do you accept credit cards?
> - How much is sales tax?
>
> **Technical Questions**
>
> - Does your software work on Linux?
> - How can I login to the app?

A few related questions might help solve this, but not sure:

[Category Archive, list subcategories of each post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/205647/category-archive-list-subcategories-of-each-post)

[Custom post type archive organized by category](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/158156/custom-post-type-archive-organized-by-category)

Comment: Could you please ellaborate on your problem and clarify what is the exact problem you're facing? Are you looking for a copy-paste solution? Or feedback on the solutions you've tried already - what have you tried?

Is it possible to display posts organized into subcategories? Yes. How? There are many ways and the linked blog post demonstrates one of them. I think post's merit is that it handles the whole thing with just one DB call instead of for example doing a query for each subcategory separately.

Comment: @AnttiKoskinen You already voted to close this, so I'm not sure why you're asking for more clarity. I think my question is fairly easy to understand, and yeah, this being Stack Exchange, I'm looking for code examples.